# Installed OMSA on RHEL 7, unable to access web interface

Tags: firewalld

I have a fresh, unmolested installation of RHEL 7.2 on a PowerEdge 2950.  Following this guide, I installed the latest version of srvadmin (8.1 by way of the Dell Repository), then started it with the following command:

```
/opt/dell/srvadmin/sbin/srvadmin-services.sh start
```

No errors were shown, and status shows running.

When I try to navigate to the web interface using https://9.9.9.9:1311, I get the standard "unable to connect" error in Firefox (similar in Chrome).

I tried adding an exception to firewalld:

```
firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=1311/tcp --permanent
```

I'm new to systemd. Is there something else I'm forgetting that might prevent the OMSA web interface from loading up?

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue: I could access via the local server at `https://localhost:1311/` but not from another computer. You need to reload the firewall rules with:

```
firewall-cmd --reload
```